# Detect and track multiple targets simultaneously using Vuforia's android SDK

Tags: android, augmented-reality, vuforia, android-augmented-reality

I have the vuforia sample called Core Features which is running fine on [Reference Link](https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/samples)

I want to detect two image targets simultaneously using vufoira. 
I found this link: [Reference Link for two images](https://library.vuforia.com//articles/Solution/Detect-and-Track-Multiple-Targets-Simultaneously)

I don't know where the `.cpp` file is or where I'm supposed to add it. I do not understand how it is supposed to work at all. Any help regarding guide lines or steps will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

First check the samples and guides at Android NDK:

https://developer.android.com/ndk/index.html

once you will be able to match up the java and cpp clode for android, download Vuforia SKD, include it in your project and go through all the tutorials and documentation they have prepared

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **"Core Features"** sample , download the **"Advanced Topic"** from Vuforia sample using Link: https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/samples

- Advanced Topic are samples that demonstrate how to work with C++ on
  Android. The Vuforia Android samples are set up so that application
  lifecycle events are handled in Java, but tracking events and
  rendering are handled natively in C++.
- Users can leverage Android SDK functionality, such as touch handling
  or networking logic, while doing the low-level graphics work
  natively. This functionality requires a way to communicate between
  Java and C++. This communication is provided by the JNI.
- You can find C++ files at: **Src>>Main>>JNI folder in Studio project**

**IMP:** You have to also set path for "NDK" in android studio to compile C++ code. please search it on google "how to set NDK in android studio"

I think following Link will be helpful for you:

https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/How-To-Communicate-Between-Java-and-C-using-the-JNI